# How to map some network on the streets using google maps

Tags: google-maps

So, I have this fiber optic network. I would like to know if is possible to map any street where my cables are crossing.

The goal I would like to achive is like sim city, where I can see where I have an electrical network. So, in some cases I can have an entire district (or even a city) mapped.

My question are to know if this is possible to achieve with google maps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this really depends on the data you have for your fiber optic network. Once you know that you have the data needed to draw whatever graphical representation of your network, there are various ways of displaying it on top of a google map. If your network data is represented with geographical locations that are connected together, maybe you can just draw the network connections as polylines? That would at least be a fairly simple approach. Here you can read about how to draw polylines in a map:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines

Using the built-in drawing features (lines, polygons, markers, circles, etc) is probably the easiest thing to do, but there are also possibilities to have more complex/custom overlays as well. You find more info about custom overlays on the URL above as well.

Comment: Thank you Knut Marius, I dont mean to migrate any data, so I was thinking in some way to draw the fiber optic network directly on the gmaps. According to polylines definition, I can achieve this. So, I need to refine my question... Once I have all network mapped, I wondering if would be possible to infer if any address are covered by my network.

Comment: If you have an address you can use the Google Geocoding API to obtain the lat/lng for that address. When you have all your polylines and the address lat/lng it should not be a big problem to calculate the distance to each of the polylines. Then you can use those distances to say if the adress is within the area covered by your network. Here is an example to get you started on the algorithm for calculating the distance between a point and a polyline: http://wtp2.appspot.com/cSnapToRouteDemo.html.